# typescript find and filter functions Object is possibly 'undefined' error

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    options.find(opt => opt.id == valueId) && options.find(opt => opt.id == valueId).title,
);
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: `find` may return undefined if no element matches. So, the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this error, because find may return `undefined` if no element matches. You may use optional chaining to get rid of that:

[TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/gWo4Pw)

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    options.find(opt => opt.id == valueId)?.title,
);
```

Typescript does not track expressions so your left of the `&&` is not being taken in account on the right.

---

Since you did not like the line break, do this:

```
const initialValue = options.find(opt => opt.id == valueId)?.title;
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);
```

Comment: It solved this problem but ı was looking for a different solution.Is there a different solution ?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you wanted to achieve. A little detail about your problem would help me to help you better, if I can.

Comment: My code does exactly what your code does but its shorter and does not spook tsc out.

Comment: vsCode does not format the code if I use options.find(opt => opt.id == valueId)?.title. Thanks for your solution

Comment: Oh, you are worried why the editor splits into two lines? That's likely because writting the expression inline makes line longer and the prettier breaks the line for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this use solved the vsCode format problem